# String replace in python - how to get only one value

Tags: python

So I have a string e.g.:

```
str="something"
```

I want to use replace function on him:

```
myString.replace(" ", "%20")
```

I want to replace all spaces.
After that i use `str` as a function argument:

```
object.fun(data1, myString)
```

When I try to run my code I have error like that:

```
raise HTTPError
```

I tried to use another variable:

```
otherString = myString.replace(" ", "%20")
object.fun(data1, data2, otherString )
```

but it's change nothing.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: If `fun` is a method inside a class, you need to call the method on an instance of the class that contains the method. E.g. `my_object.fun(data1, data2, mystring)`. If `fun` isn't a method inside a class, it shouldn't have a `self` parameter.

Comment: why do you have `**hereIsString`. That syntax is for deconstructing a dictionary but you are passing in a string. change it to just `def fun(self, data1, data2,hereIsString):
`

Comment: Your title is misleading, this as little to do with "replace" function, it's all about passing argument to a function or a class method

Answer (score 3):

its the correct way

```
def fun(data1, data2, htmlcode):
    ...
```

if its in class

```
def fun(self, data1, data2, htmlcode):
    ...
```

Comment: please flag this as answer if its correct

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be :

```
myobject.fun(data1, data2, hereIsString = otherString )
```